# Reversing a string java

Tags: java

Working on a problem to reverse a string and I am getting [C@659e0bfd when I try to use the following method to reverse a string. Anyone know what's wrong with this code?

```
    public static String reverseString(String string) {
    if ((string == null) || (string.length() <= 1)){
        return string;
    }
    char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
    char[] newString = new char[charArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++ ){
        newString[i] = charArray[(charArray.length -1)-i];
        }       
    return newString.toString();
}
```

Comment: I voted to close this question for being off-topic. You should try at least to explain your code idea, what you expect as result and the error you are getting.

Comment: @Codebender agreed. I may have been a bit overreacting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are returning  `array.toString()`.
if you want to know why it gives 
 `C@659e0bfd` [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4).

to fix this you can use

```
return new String(newString);//create string from adding all chars together
```

`public String(char[] chars)` is a overloaded constructor of String class which create a new String with array of character

Comment: @user3871995 so put the tick!

Answer (score 1):

A `char[]`'s `toString()` method is not overridden. Which means, it will give back the value provided by `Object.toString()` method.

You should instead use `return new String(newString)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, all your code, except first `if` clause can be replaced by only one string:

```
return new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
```

Secondly, you don't need nested parentheses in your `if` clause. So, the method will be the following:

```
public static String reverseString(String string) {
        if (string == null || string.length() <= 1){
            return string;
        }
        return new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
    }
```